# how to insert a variable inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables

I am trying to code in HTML + JavaScript the following kind of form/decision tree:

Question 1: from which country are you?
Answer 1: Italy
Answer 2: Japan
...

Q2: what do you like?
if Q1 = Italy, A1 = i like cats, A2 = i like music
if Q1 = Japan, A1 = i like dogs, A2 = i like sport

Q3: what age are you?
A1 = 13
A2 = 57

Result: depends on selected answers

I did succeed to code the form as well as to include the different results. Now my challenge is to display the different options for Q2 depending on Q1 answer.

My question looks like this, written in HTML:

```
<div id="question_2" hidden>
 <label>what do you like?</label>
  <select id="question_2">
          <option value="hello">i like cats</option>
          <option value="goodbye">i like music</option>
          <option disabled selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I use a function written in JS for the decision tree logic.

I would like to add these options `if Q1 = Japan, A1 = i like dogs, A2 = i like sport` ; preferably within the HTML. I thought of using variables, and have something like:

```
<div id="question_2" hidden>
 <label>what do you like?</label>
  <select id="question_2">
          <option value="hello">i like ${x}</option>
          <option value="goodbye">i like ${y}</option>
          <option disabled selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

with this logic, ideally written in JS:

```
if Q1 = A1, then x = cat and y = music
if Q1 = A2, then x = dogs and y = sport
```

Would this be possible? Any hint on what to look at?
I am a beginner. Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want the variable on the client side in javascript or do you want the variable on your backend (what are you using ? php, python, java?)

Comment: I am using HTML + JS. Ideally, I would like to the variable on the HTML, to reduce lines of code. But I am not sure this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two questions for both options Japan and Italy respectively. Then use a Javascript function which will make the question corresponding to Italy visible if the user selects Italy. Otherwise, another question will be visible if the user selects Japan. If the user selects neither Japan nor Italy, then both the questions will not be visible.

In the Javascript function, you can set the `style.display` attribute to `none` to make any question (div) invisible or set it to `block` to make the question (div) visible.

HTML

```
<div>
  <label>from which country are you?</label>
  <select id="question_1" onchange="showDiv(this)">
          <option value="italy">italy</option>
          <option value="japan">Japan</option>
          <option disabled selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</div>

<div  class = "hidden_div">
 <label>what do you like?</label>
  <select id="question_2_italy">
          <option value="hello">i like cats</option>
          <option value="goodbye">i like Music</option>
          <option disabled selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</div>

<div  class = "hidden_div">
 <label>what do you like?</label>
  <select id="question_3_japan">
          <option value="hello">i like dogs</option>
          <option value="goodbye"> i like sport</option>
          <option disabled selected="selected"></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden_div{
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
function showDiv(element)
{
         
       for ( var i = 0, len = element.options.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            opt = element.options[i];
           
            if ( opt.selected === true ) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("hidden_div")[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                    document.getElementsByClassName("hidden_div")[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That sounds like a good solution. I will try to implement it now. Will circle back here.